# Transparencies in PDF's made in R don't show up when embedded in Word or PowerPoint

Tags: r, windows, macos, pdf, ggplot2

I'm working on a Mac. If I make a PDF of a graph with some transparency, it looks fine on my computer.

```
library(ggplot2)

# Create sample data
data(cars)
cars$dist2 <- cars$dist + 20

# Call graphics device and plot
pdf(file="Test plot.pdf", width=10, height=7.5)

ggplot(data=cars, aes(x=speed, y=dist))+
  geom_line(size=3, color="blue")+
  geom_line(aes(y=dist2), size=3, color="red", alpha=.5)


dev.off()
```

[image: Screenshot of PDF on Mac]

I can load the graph into Word or PowerPoint and it looks fine too. I can send this PDF to a colleague with a Windows PC and the PDF looks good too. However, if I send the PDF embedded in a Word or PowerPoint document to someone with a PC, all semi-transparent objects become invisible.

[image: Screenshot of PDF in Word on a Windows PC]

This is probably a Microsoft/Mac problem, not necessarily an R problem but is there anything I can do with my graphics device call to prevent this? I would like to avoid strategies where I print directly to a Word or Powerpoint object or make something like a png. I want a PDF that will look good across platforms and applications.

Thank you for your help!

R version 3.4.1
MacOS 10.13.2

Comment: In my experience, importing pdfs into MS Word is almost always a bad idea.  It's just not very well supported, and in particular when you have pdf's with scatter plots of many points Word can't handle it well at all and becomes unresponsive. A high-resolution png (600 DPI or more) should always look good.

Comment: I'll probably have to give up and just use png's but I'm still curious about what actually causes this problem. There must be some kind of workaround, right?